# Regex - word followed after another word

Tags: php, regex, string, between

I have PHP app and I would like to get string "word" followed after another word. It can be followed by another strings.

1. Hello, this is status: ok
2. Hello, this is status: ok.
3. Hello, this is status: ok and I like it.

I would like to always get the **"ok"** status. How to do that please?

I have:

```
preg_match('~status:\s(.*)(?=\s.*)?~', $text, $matches);
```

But is returns everything after **status:**.

Comment: `status:\s+\K\w+` suffices.

Comment: Non regexp: https://3v4l.org/hMDXb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may ask why your current solution doesn't work?

If you see it matches a whitespace character after matching `status:` then matches up to end of line by `.*` then backtracks to find a match where a space exists. If a whitespace after `ok` doesn't exist immediately or somewhere later in string no matches is found. Solution:

```
status:\s+\K\w+
```

You don't need capturing groups and shouldn't quantify a lookahead either.

See live [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/2uceHr/1)

PHP code:

```
preg_match('~status:\s+\K\w+~', $text, $matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using a positive-lookbehind and take every word character after it.

```
(?<=status:\s)(\\w+)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IE6MHL/2)**

Answer (score 2):

You could just replace `(.*)` with `(\w*)`:

```
preg_match('~status:\s(\w*)~', $text, $matches);
```

### Demo

Another way to fix your current approach would be to make the dot in `(.*)` lazy, and then also make a slight change to your current lookahead:

```
preg_match('~status:\s(.*?)(?=\s|$)~', $text, $matches);
```

Comment: Excelent! Thank you.